# Google Sheet API Version 3.0 will eventually be deprecated. Strongly recommend all developers use the Google Sheets API v4

Tags: google-sheets-api

According to the [Google Sheet API v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#which_version_of_the_api_should_be_used), it says We strongly recommend all developers use the Google Sheets API v4.

Version 3.0 (the version described here), is documented for legacy purposes only, and will eventually be deprecated.

But I don't see any timeline.

So what is the timeline to completely phase out Google Sheet API V3 at Google?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that this is already so.
Google will not support v3 any more, will not fix bugs - but google can't stop those applications which are already work with v3. For those developers who still use v3 google left the old documentation.
If you are going to make a new application you should use v4 and don't worry about timeline)